# subset a dataframe by all combinations of (given) factor

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` like this

```
col1  col2   col3     col4
"C1"   "A"    "M"    somevalue1
"C1"   "A"    "M"    somevalue2
"C2"   "B"    "N"    somevalue3
"C3"   "B"    "N"    somevalue4
"C1"   "B"    "Y"    somevalue5
```

I'd have to get all the subsets of the dataframe given the first two columns of factors.

As for now, I got all the combinations of factors with

```
lapply(lapply(subset(df, select = c("col1", "col2")), factor), levels)
```

Then I tried to subset the dataframe by one of those factors

```
subset(df, c("col1", "col2") == c("C1", "A"))
```

But that doesn't work, nor do any other combination I could think of.

The final output should be a list containing the following dataframes

```
$1
col1  col2  col3  col4
"C1"   "A"   "M"  somevalue1
"C1"   "A"   "M"  somevalue2

$2
col1  col2  col3  col4
"C2"   "B"   "M"  somevalue3

$3
col1  col2  col3  col4
"C1"   "B"  "Y"   somevalue5

$4
col1  col2  col3  col4
"C3"   "B"  "N"   somevalue4
```

[EDIT] `subset(df, all(c("col1","col2") == c("C1", "A")))` 
also doesn't work (0 rows returned)

Comment: `split(x, list(x$col1, x$col2), drop=TRUE)` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` and `split`, i.e.

```
dd <- merge(expand.grid(unique(df$col1), unique(df$col2)), df, by.x = c('Var1', 'Var2'), 
                                                               by.y = c('col1', 'col2'))

#which gives
#  Var1 Var2 col3       col4
#1   C1    A    M somevalue1
#2   C1    A    M somevalue2
#3   C1    B    Y somevalue5
#4   C2    B    N somevalue3
#5   C3    B    N somevalue4


split(dd, cumsum(!duplicated(dd[c(1:2)])))
#$`1`
#  Var1 Var2 col3       col4
#1   C1    A    M somevalue1
#2   C1    A    M somevalue2

#$`2`
#  Var1 Var2 col3       col4
#3   C1    B    Y somevalue5

#$`3`
#  Var1 Var2 col3       col4
#4   C2    B    N somevalue3

#$`4`
#  Var1 Var2 col3       col4
#5   C3    B    N somevalue4
```